# Random malfunction of a wireless mouse

Tags: usb, power-supply, wireless-mouse

I recently noticed a rather odd problem with the operation of my Dell Wireless Mouse WM514p on a laptop Dell XPS 9550 15: the movement of the mouse becomes jerky and its positioning imprecise, which makes its use almost impossible.

The problem occurs randomly, the malfunction can last a few tens of seconds, then everything works fine again. until next time, which happens very regularly!

This problem only occurs on one of the 2 USB ports (the one next to the power plug), and this is the strangest thing, if I unplug the power to run only on battery, the behavior of the mouse becomes normal again immediately.

I was able, thanks to a USB multimeter, to check that the voltages are almost identical on the 2 USB ports (5.07V on the port where the problem occurs, and 5.08V on the other).

My laptop usually runs under Archlinux / Gnome, but being dual-booted with Windows 10, I could see that the problem also occurs in Windows (latest version, up to date including all Dell utilities), but maybe a little less frequently, I think.

The use of Dell diagnostic tools, whether on Windows or UEFI firmware, has not revealed anything abnormal.

As unplugging the power immediately solves the problem, it could suggest that the power supply would be involved.
Or, would it be the USB port itself that would fail, or the motherboard?

What do you think ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess, the leakage from the switch-mode supply is sufficient & of just the right frequency to interfere at 2.4GHz.

I have no way to prove this theory, but your empirical tests would support it.

In many cases, you can feel the effect of this leakage on metal parts of the casing, as a tingle or buzz. The only 'fix' is to either use an earthed socket [if the PSU even has a true earth, many don't] or  replace the PSU & hope you get one that doesn't leak so much [luck of the draw unless you change PSU type].

Comment: This is the original Dell power supply. I bought this laptop late 2016, and the problem appeared very recently. This would mean that the power supply was well connected to the earth so far, but for some reason, it is no longer.
I do not feel any tingling when touching the laptop, and do not hear any particular noises either.
I did experience this tingling and buzzing problem with my previous laptop (a Dell also, the XPS M1530) and the solution was actually to change the power supply.
Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be current leakage, it could be RF noise coming through the AC adapter from mains, or originating in the RF adapter itself. It might be interesting to put a ferrite bead (toroidal choke) on the DC cable between the power adapter and the laptop, and see if that helps. A snap-together ferrite bead is only a couple bucks from Radio Shack, or less than a buck a piece in 10-packs from Amazon.

Comment: Is there a simple way to check for sure if the power supply is faulty?

Comment: The leakage, voltage or RF, doesn't actually imply it's technically "faulty". There are pretty broad tolerances for these things.

Comment: In my experience, Dell is pretty stingy when it comes to their laptop PSUs, almost to the point of being unethical.  I've seen laptops come with a 65 watt brick, only for the laptop to need a 90 watt to meet it's full potential.  I've also seen plenty of "good" Dell bricks that caused problems that went away with a new PSU.  Depending on how old your brick is, your only real answer may be to get a new one, or simply avoid using the USB port next to the power connector.